# How to get HasChildren or Child count for child collection in Sitecore oData item service API

Tags: service, odata, sitecore, parent-child, children

I am using Sitecore oData Item service and need to get all children of any specific Item using Item Id which is achievable using the below API Endpoint.

Version: Sitecore 10.2

https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{AD033835-0948-4B10-B14C-04547B234552}')/Children/?sc_apikey=F645BEDE-9964-42FB-953F-2FEC7324B7EE&$count=true&$expand=Field

**Response:**

`{ "@odata.context": "https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/$metadata#Items", "@odata.count": 3, "value": [ { "Name": "Color Card", "DisplayName": "", "Path": "/sitecore/content/Test Project/website/Data/Dashboard/Color Card", "Language": "en", "Version": 1, "IsLatestVersion": true, "TemplateId": "d7ef4c8f-f98d-4b97-a30a-f8867f91a6de", "TemplateName": "Dashboard Folder", "Created": "2023-04-05T07:36:17Z", "Updated": "2023-04-05T09:27:32Z", "ParentId": "ad033835-0948-4b10-b14c-02247b252252", "Id": "f5c6e0c4-4016-4708-b616-604545111386", "Url": "https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('f5c6e0c4-4016-4708-b616-604545111386')" }, { "Name": "Side Profile", "DisplayName": "", "Path": "/sitecore/content/Test Project/website/Data/Dashboard/Side Profile", "Language": "en", "Version": 1, "IsLatestVersion": true, "TemplateId": "ec8068fa-6248-4918-ba70-161bcb18d1c3", "TemplateName": "Side Profile Folder", "Created": "2023-04-12T06:15:08Z", "Updated": "2023-04-12T06:15:08Z", "ParentId": "ad033835-0948-4b10-b14c-02247b252252", "Id": "9d9a2a23-e043-4f33-bf7d-a0e67f9c88e7", "Url": "https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('9d9a2a23-e043-4f33-bf7d-a0e67f9c88e7')" }, { "Name": "Type of user", "DisplayName": "", "Path": "/sitecore/content/Test Project/website/Data/Dashboard/Type of user", "Language": "en", "Version": 1, "IsLatestVersion": true, "TemplateId": "d7ef4c8f-f98d-4b97-a30a-f8867f91a6de", "TemplateName": "Dashboard Folder", "Created": "2023-03-28T15:10:42Z", "Updated": "2023-04-05T09:27:32Z", "ParentId": "ad033835-0948-4b10-b14c-02247b252252", "Id": "44c4f7a1-7534-4139-a210-5f0f338a8318", "Url": "https://hostname/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('44c4f7a1-7534-4139-a210-5f0f338a8318')" } ] }`

Now I want to know for each Item whether it has children or not. I tried to pas a count as part of `$expand` parameters, but no luck and also tried to find in documentation as well: [Sitecore Documentation for oData Item Service](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-odata-item-service.html)

What am I missing here?